# Trying to get property of non object

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to code a function for Wordpress Post navigation but i am getting

> Trying to get property of non object

error in lines with `$prevpost->ID` and `$nextpost->ID`, the code is this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'mm_post_nav' ) ) :
/**
 * Displays navigation to next/previous post when applicable.
 *
 * @since 1.0
 *
 * @return void
  */
function mm_post_nav() {
global $post;

// Don't print empty markup if there's nowhere to navigate.
$previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( $post->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
$next     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );
$prevpost = get_previous_post(true);
$prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevpost->ID, array(44,44) );
$nextpost = get_next_post(true);
$nextThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextpost->ID, array(44,44) );
if ( ! $next && ! $previous )
    return;
?>
<nav class="mm-post-nav" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'mm-cube' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="mm-single-nav">
        <div class="mm-prev-link">

            <?php previous_post_link( '%link', _x( '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i><span class="mm-prev-post-title"> %title</span>', 'Previous post link', 'mm-cube' ) ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="mm-next-link">

            <?php next_post_link( '%link', _x( '<span class="mm-next-post-title">%title</span><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>' , 'Next post link', 'mm-cube' ) ); ?>

        </div>
    </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
<?php
}
endif;
```

Making a var_dump($prevpost) outputs this:

```
string(0) ""
```

Comment: Can you do a var_dump() into $prevpost and $nextpost and show us the output?

Comment: I have edited the question with the result of the var_dump, thank you for your time!!

Comment: It returns empty string, because no corresponding post exists.

Comment: The answer below solves your problem, try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like following, because `$prevpost` and `$nextpost` could return `empty/null` if there is no matching posts are available.

```
$prevpost = get_previous_post(true);
if (!empty( $prevpost )) {
    $prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevpost->ID, array(44,44) );
}
$nextpost = get_next_post(true);
if (!empty( $nextpost )) {
    $nextThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextpost->ID, array(44,44) );
}
```

### Return Values (get_previous_post and get_next_post)

- Post object if successful.
- Null if global $post is not set.
- Empty string if no corresponding post exists.

Read more on `Codex` about [get_previous_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) and [get_next_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) to know how they work and what they return on any condition.

**Update:** Check the function's arguments, you have used (in both previous and next):

```
previous_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' );
```

You should use:

```
previous_post_link( '%link', _x( '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i><span class="mm-prev-post-title">%title</span>', FALSE, 'mm-cube' ) );
```

Use same order for other function. Check more on Codex about [previous_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) and [next_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)

Comment: Hi, i have tested this and the error dissapears but the pagination baheves weird and does not take you to adjacent next and previous posts ??

Comment: It's because you don't have previous or next posts

Comment: The function prototype `next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE, ' ', 'post_format' );` you have used it differently in both cases, the third param should be `Boolean`.